# NameError: name 'playground' is not defined

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-urls, nameerror

I am beginner. I am  trying to learn Django. But I face a problem. I defined app name inside my project file but django did not found it. I am using Atom as a Code Edittor. Please Any one help me..[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nbNJT.png)
this is my code
path('playground/',include(playground.urls))

File "C:\Users\Hasan\Documents\Django\STOREPRONT\STOREPRONT\urls.py", line 8, in 
path('playground/',include(playground.urls))
NameError: name 'playground' is not defined

Answer (score 1):

You have to import playground.urls:

```
import playground.urls
```

Answer (score 0):

Do :

```
include("playground.urls")
```

Instead of :

```
include(playground.urls)
```

Answer (score 0):

Wrap the string in quotes:

```
path('playground/', include('playground.urls')
```